# How can 'namespace' identifier mean something special in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, identifier

I found following in javascript code

```
function calculateURI(uri) {
        return (namespace.push.configuration.uriPrefix || '') + uri + (namespace.push.configuration.uriSuffix || '');
}
```

also I found in other place

```
ice.push.configuration.contextPath = 'something';
```

So, I wonder, how these assignments relate? Does 'namespace' identifier have special meaning? Or it is just a name like 'ice'?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

People saying that 'namespace' means nothing special.

But I am trying to set 'namespace.push.configuration.uriPrefix' as I see it in Firebug debugger. First it was '' and was need it to contain some path. Initially I have assigned

```
namespace.push.configuration.uriPrefix = ice.push.configuration.contextPath + '/';
```

but it was remanining empty.

Then I tried to assign

```
ice.push.configuration.uriPrefix = ice.push.configuration.contextPath + '/';
```

and have 'namespace.push.configuration.uriPrefix' filled!

How can it be if 'namespace' have no special meaning???

**UPDATE 2**

May be they did some overloading? The overal structure of their script looks like the following

```
if (!window.ice) {
    window.ice = new Object;
}  
if (!window.ice.icepush) {

    (function(namespace) {

        window.ice.icepush = true;

        //....
        // a lot of functions
        // ....

     })(window.ice);
 }
```

everywhere in the functions 'namespace' is used and never it is spelled as 'ice'.

Can this patterd do some overloading of 'namespace' variable?

Comment: Did you even try googling it? The first result gives me the answer. http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+namespace

Comment: It's just a name. Unless your using the `namespace` keyword that's part of the non standard E4X extension in firefox

Comment: Off course I googled and read that article, but found nothing special about 'namespace' name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as I can't comment on your original question, I'll put this here.

There area two main ways of setting up a name space, Objects { } and Functions (like above)

What they are doing is just wrapping all of their code in an anonymous function and then calling it (this sets the scope or the namespace)

```
( function(variable) {  
    /* Code to execute using 'variable' */ 
} )(item_to_fill_variable)
```

Which is basically the same as:

```
function withNameSpace( namespace ) { 
    /* Code to execute using 'namespace' */ 
}
withNameSpace( window.ice );
```

This sets (in your example) "namespace" to "window.ice"

Now while inside of the anonymous function, you can use "namespace" to access "window.ice".

When outside of the anonymous function, "namespace" will be undefined and you wont be able to set it.  This is more than likely what you were doing when trying to set `namespace.push.configuration.uriPrefix = ice.push.configuration.contextPath + '/';`

Answer (score 2):

the word namespace in javascript is nothing more than variable name.

Comment: @Dims The reserved words in JavaScript are defined here: http://es5.github.com/#x7.6.1 The word "namespace" is not among them...

Comment: I saw this but I should believe my eyes. I does mean something special somehow!